# Azure Private endpoint for service bus

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have created the service bus namespace using bicep and also created Private Endpoint for the service bus, but privatenedpoints are not deploying. Do I need to add subnets for creating private endpoints?

```
param service_bus_private_endpoint_Name string
param subscriptionsID string
param resourceGroupName string
PrivateEndpointId : param privateEndpointId string= '/subscriptions/${subscriptionsID}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/privateEndpoints/${service_bus_private_endpoint_Name}'

resource privateEndpointConnections 'Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces/privateEndpointConnections@2022-10-01-preview' = {
  name: service_bus_private_endpoint_Name
  properties: {
    privateEndpoint: {
      id : privateEndpointId
    }
    
    privateLinkServiceConnectionState: {
      description: 'Approved'
      status: 'Auto-Approved'
    }
    provisioningState: 'Succeeded'
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, every private endpoint must be associated to a subnet during the deployment, as it will in practice have a network interface "attached" to this subnet.

You can refer to this example from the official documentation for creating private endpoints using Bicep, where you can see it defines a vnet, a subnet and then the private endpoint referring the subnet and the sub-resource (in your case the servicebus namespace).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/create-private-endpoint-bicep?tabs=CLI